# Delta_V from gravitational interaction at relativistic speeds

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, orbital-motion

This question was prompted by a separate question about [planetary encounters](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41423/scholarly-work-on-the-gravitational-disruption-of-a-rocky-planet-by-a-close-pass). The small delta_V from a high-speed near miss of two equal bodies was calculated as GM/dv, where M is the mass of either of the two bodies, d is the minimum separation, and v is their relative velocity.

I'm curious if this formula still holds at relativistic speeds?  At a simplistic level, the relativistic mass seems to increase at the same rate that time-dilation would reduce the effective field, so the delta_V would simply limit at GM/dc as the velocity approaches the speed of light (this delta_V would be from the reference frame of one of the two bodies assumed stationary). Is this limit correct and is the delta_V still along the direction of d?

Comment: If we're using general relativity to do this, it's going to require approximation, because the two body problem in general relativity is famously difficult to solve, and we'd have to worry about things like the gravitational radiation emitted during the process.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer Good point.  If we limit it to small deflections, delta_V << c, that seems to imply GM/dc << c or rs << d, i.e. the closest approach is still much larger than the Schwartzchild radius.  Could we perhaps argue that the gravitational radiation is a second-order effect?  I'm also thinking, how complicated can this problem really be?  After all, there are only three parameters M,d, and v.  (here I'm speaking from a position of complete ignorance!)

Comment: The "equal mass" part is the thing that makes it hard to not just immediately give an answer.  Typically the "mathematically easy" case is the extreme mass ratio case where you can say $m/M ~0$.  There's no equivalent of the "center of mass/ reduced mass" trick fofr the Newtonian gravitational two-body lagrangian.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer If m << M allows it to be solved for relativistic velocities, that would be great. The corresponding Newtonian delta_V formulae are 2GM/dv for the little mass and 2Gm/dv for the big mass.